# How to go to the previously edited file in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I know there is `Ctrl+Up/Down` but that's not what I'm looking. `next_view` and `prev_view` are for tabs/view that are positioned close to each other but they are not necessarily previous and next files that I edited.

What I'm looking for is more liker what in vim works as `Ctrl+^` except `Ctrl+^` works only within the current buffer and I would like it to be project wide.

For example, say I opened a file via `Ctrl+P`, then another one. Now they may or may not be positioned next to each other but I would like to go to that previously edited/opened file by calling magic `go-to-previously-edited-file` command.

Comment: Did you checkout the `Goto` menu in Sublime? There are **many** shortcuts for quick navigation.

Comment: @zwippie, thanks for the suggestion. `go-to-previous-in-stack` is closer but it's still not vim's `Ctrl+^` in a sense that if you press it second time it goes to pre-previous file.